# How to save rss feeds?

Tags: php, rss

I am a newbie to programming and recently made a rss feeds for my app. Now can anyone gimme a idea bout how I can save rss feeds to my local box from an external rss feeds url.
Thanks

Comment: How are you getting your rss feeds? If you retreieve it as XML, you can use save the XML anyway you wanted

Comment: What do you mean with 'local box'?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you wanted to read the contents and then save to a local file, you could do the following:

```
$feedurl = "http://someurl/feed/";
$feedme = file_get_contents($feedurl);
if($feedme):
  $fh = fopen('path/to/newfeed.xml', 'w+'); //create new file if not exists
  fwrite($fh, $feedme) or die("Failed to write contents to new file"); //write contents to new XML file
  fclose($fh) or die("failed to close stream resource"); //close resource stream
else:
  die("Failed to read contents of feed at $feedurl");
endif;
```

That is a REALLY simple example to get you started.

Comment: Note, it does not HAVE to be an XML file, but considering that an RSS feed is a form of XML, it is good practice. You could then read the contents of your saved file, add your respective RSS/XML headers in php, and echo out the contents, this will show your feed in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) to retrieve the data and any xml-parser to analyze. Or just use google ;-) -> [using-php-curl-to-read-rss-feed-xml](http://ditio.net/2008/06/19/using-php-curl-to-read-rss-feed-xml/)